# Initial Git push of large project fails- VPN Setting?

Tags: git, push

Using a development IDE, an initial Git push fails with the following error message-

> "Failed to write chunk."
> ...or...
> "Failed to write chunk footer."
> ...or...
> "Failed to write chunk header."

...then...

> "The connection with the server was terminated abnormally"

I am over VPN to a VM.
Fellow team member with same development IDE and same project successfully completes the initial Git push. They do not use a VPN/VM.

If I use TortoiseGit (same underlying Git client to VM via VPN), the initial push succeeds.
In its displayed log, it seems that TortoiseGit is compressing the project.
The development IDE *may* be compressing, or not. It does not disclose that in its output log.

One similar posting here on Stackoverflow intimated that VPN settings need to be modified. If so, what are those setting to look for?

Please advise.
Thank you.

Comment: I often have difficulties doing large pushes or clones over slow VPN network connections. My work-around is to just avoid the situation in the first place. Sorry, I know that's not very helpful! To avoid the situation, my first approach is to avoid creating large Git repos (use LFS if necessary).

Comment: Note that "failed to write chunk" does not appear anywhere in the Git source: this message is not coming from Git at all. (It seems to be in libgit2sharp, a Microsoft thingy.)

Comment: Potentially more helpful, it's not just VPN settings you should look at, there might be timeout settings on the server itself causing you trouble.

Comment: My mention of compression and VPN may be red herrings. Please do not allow me to introduce them as such. Please evaluate this issue without those two possibilities as well. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for these quick responses. Can timeout setting value be changed by myself as a User for just the session? If it is a timeout issue, how is it that TortoiseGit avoids this when the dev IDE does not?

Comment: I once had problems pushing to a repo via `git+https` because the **http-server limited the upload size**.